# UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame notification not sent when moving undocked keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uikeyboard

I am trying to make a toolbar that is always above the keyboard, pretty much like in Apple's native Messages app. If you take a closer look at that app on the iPad, try undocking the keyboard and the dragging it around by holding than button in its bottom right. You will notice that Apple's toolbar tracks the keyboard's position quite nicely.

Trying to replicate that behavior, I subscribed to both the keyboard-will-change-frame and keyboard-did-change-frame notifications. However, to my disappointment I found that the first one is sent when the user starts the dragging, and the latter is sent when the keyboard snaps to its final position, but there are no notifications I could find that are sent in between. Am I missing something? Here's what I am talking about:

This is the code I use to subscribe to notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidChangeFrame:) name:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

These are my listener functions:

```
- (void)keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)notification{

    NSLog(@"will change");
    // [self alignToolbarForKeyboard:notification action:@"will_change_frame"];

}

- (void)keyboardDidChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)notification{

    NSLog(@"did change");
    // [self alignToolbarForKeyboard:notification action:@"did_change_frame"];

}
```

I commented out the call both listener functions make to make sure it's not blocking anything. Is there a notification type I do not know of? I did look at the UIWindow reference but couldn't find anything beyond what I already have. Just to make sure, I also checked whether the show/hide notifications are sent during the movement. They aren't.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that the toolbar is an `inputAccessoryView`? This might be a lot easier than tracking keyboard frame changes.

Comment: I'll give it another try, but in my previous attempts the toolbar would get hidden with the keyboard, yet I prefer to keep it visible at all times. Still, maybe I'll find a way with the input accessory view.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to specially handle the case of the keyboard being dismissed so you show the toolbar at the bottom. But at least you can handle that event.

Comment: @arik-so Did you get anything working? :)

Comment: Yeah, more or less. My solution was to create two identical toolbars, and make one the input accessory view of the other's text field. Then, depending on whether the keyboard was shown or not, I would either show or hide the other toolbar, which was not an input accessory view.

Comment: Another idea I'm currently contemplating is making just one toolbar, and a 1 square pixel with zero opacity the input accessory view of a text field. Then, through key value observation detect all of its movement, and move the toolbar accordingly. I'm not yet sure whether it would work, though.